# Typed NSUserDefaults

Tags: generics, swift

I was looking around for a Swift wrapper around `NSUserDefaults` and found some very nice projects (see e.g. [SwiftyUserDefaults](https://github.com/radex/SwiftyUserDefaults)). Unfortunately, it all boils down to stringy keys galore...

Eventually, I tried something myself and came up with the code below. I'm tempted to use it in production, but do not have much experience with user defaults and would be grateful for any comments regarding the safety of the solution below:

We start by declaring a pair of protocols that we can use to tag the types we wish to support:

```
public protocol UserDefaultsObject: AnyObject {}
public protocol UserDefaultsValue {
    var userDefault: UserDefaultsObject { get }
    init(UserDefaultsObject)
}
```

Tag all the classes supported by `NSUserDefaults`:

```
import Foundation

extension NSNumber: UserDefaultsObject {}
extension NSString: UserDefaultsObject {}
// etc...
```

We declare a `struct` because that allows us to decide on mutability simply but instantiating a `UserDefault` value as a `let` or a `var`:

```
public struct UserDefault<T: UserDefaultsValue> {

    public let key: String
    public var value: T? {
        get { return store }
        set {
            store = newValue
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(store?.userDefault, forKey: key)
        }
    }

    public init(key: String, defaultValue: T?) {
        self.key = key
        if let object: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) {
            let userDefaultsObject = object as! UserDefaultsObject // this is the crucial line
            store = T(userDefaultsObject)
        } else {
            store = defaultValue
        }
    }

    private var store: T?
}
```

Now we can extend as many types as we wish. Let's start with `Int`:

```
extension Int: UserDefaultsValue {
    public var userDefault: UserDefaultsObject {
        return NSNumber(integer: self)
    }
    public init(_ object: UserDefaultsObject) {
        self = (object as! NSNumber).integerValue
    }
}
```

Which can be used like so:

```
var life = UserDefault(key: "Life %", defaultValue: 100) {
    didSet {
        // observe
    }
}

life.value = 50
```

We can add support for `String`:

```
extension String: UserDefaultsValue {
    public var userDefault: UserDefaultsObject {
        return NSString(string: self)
    }
    public init(_ object: UserDefaultsObject) {
        self = object as! String
    }
}
```

And use it like so (note that we can start with a `nil` default):

```
var answer = UserDefault<String>(key: "answer to life the universe and everything", defaultValue: nil)

answer.value ?? "42"

answer.value = "42"

answer.value //--> 42
```

And so on, we can similarly extend any type whatsoever, as long as we can think of a way of converting it to and from `UserDefaultObject`...

I'm primarily concerned with safety at this point (will this launch any missiles, etc.), but would certainly welcome any ideas about possible improvements as well as discussion about the general approach of wrapping individual user default values rather than `NSUserDefaults` class or its standard instance.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers!

Comment: Rolled back a bunch of revisions. Please see: [What you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765). If your question has changed, ask a new question.

Comment: Why do you think that my question has changed @rolfi? It hasn't, at all. Please revert your rollback! Consider, if I did ask a new question with the content of what you rolled back... impossible, it would be the same question!

Comment: @milos a new question wouldn't be constricted purely to what was rolled back.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I'll add that content as an answer, though in this particular case I think it would have improved the question without affecting any existing answers (one, at the moment)...

Comment: When I tried to add an answer this popped up: "Are you sure you want to answer your question? Comment if you're trying to respond to an answer. Edit your question if you need to add more details." The content you rolled back clearly constitutes the "more details" here (just making the question clearer). Are you positively sure that rolling back is the most profitable option? Who, in this particular case, will benefit from rolling it out of existence?

Comment: @milos perhaps you would like to [join us in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor)?

Answer (score 3):

Our constructors would be better as failable initializers.

Nothing prevents us from passing a wrapped `NSNumber` to the `String` initializer, or a wrapped `String` to the `Int` initializer.  In your code, this would simply crash.  It would be better if our initializers were allowed to fail.

First, we need to change the protocol to define a failable initializer rather than a non-failable initializer:

```
public protocol UserDefaultsValue {
    var userDefault: UserDefaultsObject { get }
    init?(UserDefaultsObject)
}
```

Now, write the initializers as failable:

```
extension Int: UserDefaultsValue {
    public var userDefault: UserDefaultsObject {
        return NSNumber(integer: self)
    }
    public init?(_ object: UserDefaultsObject) {
        if let number = object as? NSNumber {
            self = number.integerValue
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

---

We can clean up our `UserDefault` constructor a bit as well.

> ```
> if let object: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) {
>     let userDefaultsObject = object as! UserDefaultsObject // this is the crucial line
>     store = T(userDefaultsObject)
> }
> ```

Like our initializers which should be failable, this runs the risk of crashing if `object` turns out to be some type which isn't a `UserDefaultsObject`.  We can clean this up slightly though.  This can look cleaner and be safer:

```
if let object = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) as? UserDefaultsObject {
    store = T(object)
}
```

The conditional will fail if:

- There isn't already an object for this key.
- Whatever `NSUserDefaults` returns for this key cannot be interpreted as a UserDefaultsObject.

There is one major concern I have, however, and I don't know of the right solution right now.

Consider the following situation, I save an `NSNumber` object to the key `"abckey"`.  Now, I do this:

```
let s = UserDefault(key: "abckey", defaultValue: "Hello World")
```

In your version of the code, this will *happen* will crash because this line:

```
let userDefaultsObject = object as! UserDefaultObject
```

Will have no problem converting an `NSNumber` to a `UserDefaultObject` (assuming you fixed it with `extension NSNumber: UserDefaultsObject {}`), but the following line will be problematic:

```
store = T(userDefaultsObject)
```

Because the type of `T` will be a `String` (we passed a `String` for `defaultValue` argument).

Our `extension String: UserDefaultsValue` will have to include *several* constructors which take every sort of possible thing that can be stored in `NSUserDefaults`.  And some of those simply won't make sense.

Comment: Thanks for your response **nhgrif**. Notice the comment `// this is the crucial line`: this is the point at which you can guarantee that the `object` is indeed a `UserDefaultsObject`, since it just came out of `NSUserDefaults` method. This is the point of bridge between the two protocols (`UserDefaultsObject` and `UserDefaultsValue`), and why failable initialisers are not needed (or preferred). My bigger problem is that, the `UserDefault` values are not KVO-compliant. To make them `dynamic` however is pretty hard...

Comment: All that your commented line does is guarantee that `object` is a `UserDefaultsObject`.  It doesn't guarantee that the generic type of our struct has a constructor for the *specific* type of object that our `UserDefaultsObject` actually has.  And a failable initializer is going to be better than a crash (which can happen with your code).

Comment: I edited the answer in attempt to explain a bit better (though it really is getting quite long). One way of thinking about it is to come up with a concrete scenario that would fail at runtime and no sooner (prevention of which is the whole point of "Typed NSUserDefaults". In your example, I'm not sure how would you manage to save `NSNumber` in place of `String` (or vice versa) using this API – and if you did, you'd really want to know about it before shipping the app :)... If I'm wrong about any of this, however, I'll be really grateful to you for getting to me through my thick head!

Comment: Notice also that a concrete type is set in place of `T` at the point of declaring the user default key. Henceforth, all interaction with `NSUserDefaults` is strictly typed. If you get it to compile, it should never crash. It will always be the `userDefault` property of `T`, whatever it is, that will be called. Let me know what you think!

Comment: @milos Nothing prevents you from creating two different `UserDefault` instances with the same key but different types.  Nothing prevents you from changing a key's type in an update.

Comment: That's true. Those are hard problems, as anyone who ever worked with CoreData knows. How much one would be willing to invest in covering for those potentialities depends on the size of the team and modularity of the codebase. A well designed architecture should make them very unlikely to begin with. For example, having all these properties wrapped up in a global singleton? Whatever the means, the point is certainly to declare a property only once. Do you think the API should enforce this?

Answer (score 0):

#### 1. UserDefault property wrapper (core api)

I wish I could go back and edit my first attempt towards “Typed NSUserDefaults”, but that would not be fair to my kind reviewers, so here I’m describing a solution that I’ve been enjoying to work with for only a couple of days (so anything can still be wrong with it).

The basic idea is simple:

1. String key written only once per property, EVER, thereon reference the defaults with strictly typed properties.
2. Achieve this by wrapping individual properties, rather than `NSUserDefaults` class or its “standard” instance.

The inescapable task then is to provide protocols that will guarantee successful conversion from the types you want to work with to (and from) the plist types that `NSUserDefaults` can handle:

```
public protocol UserDefaultsObject: AnyObject {}

public protocol UserDefaultsValue {
    var userDefault: UserDefaultsObject { get }
    init(UserDefaultsObject)
}
```

We'll use `UserDefaultsObject` protocol to tag all the plist types we are interested in (`NSNumber`, `NSString`, etc.). We'll use `UserDefaultsValue` protocol to complete the conversion contract. If we extend, say, `Int` to conform to `UserDefaultsValue` protocol, we'll have a way of converting to and from `NSNumber` behind the `UserDefaultsObject`... we'll come back to that later.

Let's now introduce the wrapper type for every user default property:

```
import Foundation

public class UserDefault<T: UserDefaultsValue> {
    
    public let key: String
    
    public var userDefault: T? {
        get {
            if let object: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey(key) {
                return T(object as! UserDefaultsObject)
            }
            return nil
        }
        set {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setObject(newValue?.userDefault, forKey: key)
        }
    }
    
    public var registeredDefault: T? {
        if let object: AnyObject = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().volatileDomainForName(NSRegistrationDomain)[key] {
            return T(object as! UserDefaultsObject)
        }
        return nil
    }
    
    public init(key: String, defaultValue: T?) {
        self.key = key
        if let defaultValue = defaultValue {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().registerDefaults([key: defaultValue.userDefault])
        }
    }
    
    public func reset() {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObjectForKey(key)
    }
}
```

A property of this type stores nothing else but the string key of the user default. Its usefulness is that the desired type of the user default value is now immutably tied to that key (later we’ll address the issue of uniquing these properties in your app).

Another convenience is that the initialiser simultaneously registered the default value (if you get the property before setting it, or if you wish to let the user reset the defaults, or just this default).

Now, as you can see from the discussion in the comments, there’s been some anxiety about that `as!` at the heart of this `class`, so rather than immediately implementing support for any types we wish to use, let us see what happens if we try to use this tiny api without further ado.

Let’s say we wish to manage a `name` property of type `String`:

```
let name = UserDefault(key: "Name", defaultValue: "John Doe")
```

Ups, there is a compiler error:

```
// Cannot invoke initializer for type 'UserDefault<T>' with an argument list of type '(key: String, defaultValue: String)'
```

That's a very nice, helpful compile-time error! The problem obviously is not in the first argument since `String` is exactly what the `init` wants there. If we look at why we can't use `String` for the second argument, why it can’t be the `T` in `UserDefault<T>` then we see, from the type declaration, that `T` must conform to `UserDefaultsValue`. Ok, so let’s conform:

```
extension String: UserDefaultsValue {
    public var userDefault: UserDefaultsObject {
        return NSString(string: self)
    }
    public init(_ object: UserDefaultsObject) {
        self = object as! String
    }
}
```

Ups again! We get another error from the compiler:

```
// 'NSString' is not convertible to 'UserDefaultsObject'
```

This is as good as it gets when it comes to compiler error messages! No interpretation needed, lets get on with the arduous chore of extending `NSString` to conform to `UserDefaultsObject`:

```
extension NSString: UserDefaultsObject {}
```

Done!

Now we can declare and use our `name` property forevermoere...

```
let name = UserDefault(key: "Name", defaultValue: "John Doe")

println(name.userDefault) //--> Optional("John Doe")

name.userDefault = "Dr Who?"

println(name.userDefault) //--> Optional("Dr Who?")

println(name.registeredDefault) //--> Optional("John Doe")

name.reset()

println(name.userDefault) //--> Optional("John Doe")
```

But if we try:

```
let age = UserDefault<Int>(key: "Age", defaultValue: nil)
```

We get another helpful error, since we did not yet provided support for `Int` and its analogue `NSNumber`... (Note also that the api allows you to start with a `nil`, which is often preferable, as in the case of age for example.):

```
// Type 'Int' does not conform to protocol 'UserDefaultsValue'
```

In this way you do not need to implement support for any types you do not need the support for, until you do… And once you do, any property of that concrete type will always use it's own type's implementations of `var userDefault: UserDefaultsObject { get }` and `init(UserDefaultsObject)`... no error possible!

The scary looking `as!` is therefore no more than a way of tagging the plist types coming out of the `NSUserDefaults` as plist types that they are. I could have called this protocol `PlistClass` but that would need further considerations I’m not motivated to make at present.

I promissed to discuss the question of uniquing these properties, but this is already too long, so I'll leave it for a subsequent answer... And thank's for reading this far!

Comment: And `as!` still **crashes** if we try instantiate two `UserDefault` objects for the same key with different types.  This is a run time **crash**, not a compile time error.

Comment: Yes, but you would want it to crush, as soon as possible. This would be symptomatic of gross negligence anyway and show complete disregard of the purpose of the api. Why on earth would you use it anyway if you plan to type out the strings as usual? Apple's apis juggle thousands of string constants, "nothing is stopping you" (as you put it) to type these strings yourself or bind new constants to those same strings, etc, etc. Do you really see no virtue in this code whatsoever? Must I abandon my attempt at adding types to `NSUserDefaults` altogether? Is it SO much worse than other attempts?

Comment: I guess I should also mention that my experience thus far with this solution is that it is working rather beautifully and that my core code got noticeably decluttered and clearer in its intent.

Comment: It's not that I see no virtue.  It's just that I think you're stopping *way* short and that while you solve some problems, you introduce new ones.  I'm personally never interested in any chunk of code that intends to serve as a wrapper around existing Apple stuff if it can't solve problems without introducing new ones.  This idea of yours has potential, but you can't just expect anyone to use this over `NSUserDefaults` when this only goes so far... you're trying to get people to entirely stop using a very common Apple class... your code has to be *really* good...

Answer (score 0):

#### 2. Going Global - declaring a property only once

The single most difficult aspect of persisting data is maintaining the integrity of the data model/format. In the case of the proposed solution towards strictly typed `NSUserDefaults`, this boils down to uniquing the `UserDefault<T>` property declarations that guarantee the key-type contract described in my previous answer and in the question itself. In other words, the idea is precisely NOT that you declare the property again and again every time you need access to the underlying user default!

Of course, there are many ways of ensuring data model’s integrity and uneventful versioning, each more elaborate than the other. The whole point of using `NSUserDefaults` (and not, say, `CoreData`) is that it is already there, that it is the most light weight persistence solution on Apple’s platforms…

So my personal take on the issue of uniquing the property declarations is, well, mind numbingly  boring:

Stick something along the lines of the following code in a `Global.swift`:

```
struct Global {
    static let name = UserDefault(key: "Name", defaultValue: "John Doe")
    static let age = UserDefault<Int>(key: "Age", defaultValue: nil)
    static let ok = UserDefault(key: "It's OK", defaultValue: true)
    // and so on...
}
```

You can now get to these from anywhere like so:

```
if let name = Global.name.userDefault {
    // use name
}
```

Notice however that we can often be sure that a property has a value because we've set the default value:

```
if Global.ok.userDefault! {
    // do an ok thing
}
```

Of course, someone might still set `Global.ok.userDefault` to `nil` and the above would crush, in which case we could do:

```
if Global.ok.userDefault ?? Global.ok.registeredDefault! {
    // this is guaranteed, but no fun
}
```

To make it easier to make use of this approach, but without imposing a non `nil` requirement, we can introduce some dedicated operators:

```
postfix operator >? {}
postfix operator >>? {}
postfix operator >>! {}

postfix func >? <T: UserDefaultsValue> (x: UserDefault<T>) -> T? {
    return x.userDefault
}

postfix func >>? <T: UserDefaultsValue> (x: UserDefault<T>) -> T? {
    return x.userDefault ?? x.registeredDefault
}

postfix func >>! <T: UserDefaultsValue> (x: UserDefault<T>) -> T {
    return x.userDefault ?? x.registeredDefault!
}
```

This gives you a prettier access to your property at three different levels of confidence that it has a value:

```
if let ok = Global.ok>? {
    // ok.userDefault if any
}

if let ok = Global.ok>>? {
    // ok.userDefault ?? ok.registeredDefault if any
}

if Global.ok>>! {
    // ok.userDefault ?? ok.registeredDefault!
}
```

Note that one can now Alt-click and Command-click on custom operators as well, giving you instant access to their api/documentation (I'm using Xcode 6.3.1). This means we should no longer be too squeamish about introducing new operators – where they do good.

As **@nhgrif** pointed out in his answer an comments, failing to enforce unique binding of a string key to a property may lead to a crash, as in the following scenario:

```
struct Global {
    static let name = UserDefault(key: "Player's Name", defaultValue: "Jane Doe")
}

println(Global.name.userDefault) //--> Optional("Jane Doe")
```

then elsewhere in the code!

```
let rogue = UserDefault(key: "Player's Name", defaultValue: 007)

println(rogue.userDefault) //--> Optional(7)

println(Global.name.userDefault) //--> crash: Could not cast value of type '__NSCFNumber' (0x7fff787fb7b8) to 'NSString' (0x7fff7787c6d8).
```

As crushes go, this one produced a rather nice error message and it happened immediately, on the next debug run. So the degree to which this is a deal breaker with regards to the proposed solution as a whole is a meter of disagreement. In fact, I was so stubborn about the low probabilities this would ruin anyone's life (especially given the lightweight nature of `NSUserDefaults`) and the fact that silent failures with the usual practice have much greater chance of going unnoticed, that I failed to consider a simple measure that would go a long way in alleviating such concerns to begin with.

Notice that the only problem with the crush above is not that it happened, it bloody should, but that it did not happen at the line of code where the `rogue` property was declared! We can ensure this happens with the following addition right at the start of the `UserDefault.init`:

```
let existingKeys = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().volatileDomainForName(NSRegistrationDomain).keys
if Set(existingKeys).contains(key) {
    fatalError("The key <\(key)> has already been used.")
}
```

This produces a gorgeous and timely error:

```
// fatal error: The key <Player's Name> has already been used.
```

The reason this works is that the proposed solution is adding to registered defaults piecemeal, one by one, which was always kind a cool about it. But because registered defaults are not persisted, we can use them to check if the string key has already been used somewhere in the code. Now, this does not prevent all possible ways of abusing this tiny api, but it does the biggest, most probable class of them. Thanks to **@nhgrif** for pushing for a solution of this kind!

Comment: These operators will certainly make the code confusing.  And while this `Global` struct makes the `UserDefaults` more convenient to use, still nothing is done to prevent the misuse of the `UserDefaults` class that will cause a crash if an extra is instantiated outside of this global struct with a same key and different type.  The *core* problem here is that this will *crash*!  Accessing this normally through `NSUserDefaults` certainly provides weird, unintended behavior, but the application will not *crash*.

Comment: Yes, but this would have to be a declaration with a **different** property name, and the **same** string key! Personally, I can't imagine forgetting the simple rule that I should never see a property declaration anywhere, whatsoever, save for `Global.swift`. No api in existence can pass such scepticism. Certainly there is many more ways of screwing up with silent failings when you use the defaults in the usual way...

Comment: Yes, but are you writing this code only for your personal use?  Or are you writing this code for others to also use?  If you're writing it for personal use, you probably don't need a review.  If others are using it, others are misusing it.  If we are writing code that others will use, we need to program as defensively as possible and eliminate as many possible crashes that are caused directly by our code as possible.

Comment: I precisely need a review if I intend to use it! That's like the first tenet of the site! I certainly come here to learn and not to teach. Did I misunderstand the purpose of the site. Would you discourage me from using it unless I am ready to make guarantees to other programmers? You are obviously a very experienced member and it wont take much from you to pursued me either way...

Comment: I like the site's slogan: "We're working together to improve the skills of programmers worldwide"

Comment: If you want to chat about it, you know where to find us.

Comment: **@nhgrif** please have a look at the additional information towards the end of this answer where I tried to address the largest class of errors that you raised the concern about.

Answer (score 0):

#### 3. Observing strictly typed user defaults

The final piece of the puzzle is a way of easily observing the changes of the underlining value of the `UserDefault<T>` property. To that end we can introduce the simplest of observer wrappers:

```
public class UserDefaultObserver: NSObject {
    
    public let userDefaultsKey: String
    public let handler: () -> ()
    
    public init(key: String, handler: () -> ()) {
        self.userDefaultsKey = key
        self.handler = handler
        super.init()
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().addObserver(self, forKeyPath: key, options: .allZeros, context: nil)
    }
    
    public override func observeValueForKeyPath(keyPath: String, ofObject object: AnyObject, change: [NSObject : AnyObject], context: UnsafeMutablePointer<Void>) {
        handler()
    }
    
    deinit {
        NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().removeObserver(self, forKeyPath: userDefaultsKey)
    }
}
```

I imagine this needs no explanation, except to note that the callback need not pass an info since the property itself will provide the context:

```
public extension UserDefault {
    
    public func observe(handler: () -> ()) -> UserDefaultObserver {
        return UserDefaultObserver(key: key, handler: handler)
    }
}
```

Putting it all together now, we can easily access, modify and observe all user defaults:

```
let okObserver = Global.ok.observe() {
    if Global.ok>>! {
        // it's ok
    } else {
        // not ok
    }
}
```